# Separate first and last names with for loop

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I'm working on a batch that creates a .txt-file from a record. The file will be processed later by another program.

The record looks like this at the moment:

```
11111;Lastname Firstname SecondFirstname;1234567;SomeText
22222;Lastname Firstname;1254557;SomeText
33333;Lastname Firstname;1234567;SomeText
```

I would like to have a semicolon between the last name and the first name. The problem is the sentences with two first names. Here should be no semicolon between the names.

In the end it should look like this:

```
11111;Lastname;Firstname SecondFirstname;1234567;SomeText
22222;Lastname;Firstname;1254557;SomeText
33333;Lastname;Firstname;1234567;SomeText
```

Does anyone have an idea here?
I have tried the following but that does not solve the problem with the two first names:

```
type nul>tmp.txt
for /f "delims=: tokens=1*" %%i in ('findstr /n "^" "test_output.txt"') do set "Zeile=%%j" &call :sub
move /y "tmp.txt" "test_output.txt"

goto :eof


:sub
if not defined Zeile (
    >>tmp.txt echo.
    goto :eof
)
>>tmp.txt echo %Zeile: =;%
goto :eof
```

Comment: What's a *»second first name«*?? ;-)

Comment: How do you propose to deal with a name like `van der Waals Johannes Diderik`?

Comment: @Magoo: Mr. van has a lot of forenames `:D`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsing the first time by the `;` delimiter and parsing the second token (the third, if you take the line numbers into account) a second time by a `<SPACE>` delimiter (with `tokens=1,*`) solves your problem:

```
@echo off
(for /f "tokens=1-3,* delims=;:" %%A in ('findstr /n "^" "test_output.txt"') do (
if "%%B"=="" echo/
  for /f "tokens=1,*" %%M in ("%%C") do (
   echo/%%B;%%M;%%N;%%D
  )
))>tmp.txt
goto :eof
```

(redirecting the whole output at once is a lot faster than redirecting single lines - especially with big files)

Answer (score 2):

You need two nested `for /F` the first to split at the semicolon, the 2nd to split at the space limited to 2 splits.

Using uppercase `%A` and lowercase `%a` for the meta variables, in cmd line:

```
for /F "tokens=1-3* delims=;" %A in (test_output.txt) do @for /F "tokens=1*" %a in ("%B") do @Echo %A;%a;%b;%C;%D
```

In a batch file saving to new_output.txt:

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\06\04\SO_56443069.cmd
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

(for /F "tokens=1-3* delims=;" %%A in (test_output.txt
  ) do for /F "tokens=1*" %%a in ("%%B"
  ) do Echo %%A;%%a;%%b;%%C;%%D
) >new_output.txt
```

Sample output:

```
> type new_output.txt
11111;Lastname;Firstname SecondFirstname;1234567;SomeText
22222;Lastname;Firstname;1254557;SomeText
33333;Lastname;Firstname;1234567;SomeText
```

Comment: I'd use `tokens=1-3*` instead (you don't know what `SomeText` is) and use `%%A` rather than `%A` due to the [tag:batch-file] tag (but no [tag:cmd])...

Comment: TheDude put some additional work into keeping empty lines, so I guess he really *wants*  to keep them (even if there is no empty line in the example data)